# Safely unwrap optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to create a new array of colors. Everything is working fine.

But I don't want to force unwrap `$0.color!` because the app crashes sometimes when the value is nil.

How can I leave it as an optional? If I just delete the `!` I get an error asking me to unwrap it.

```
let newArray = oldDict.map{ UIColor(hexString: $0.color!)}
```

Comment: You said `oldDict`, but is that really a dictionary? Surely that must be an array?!? And do you care whether the `newArray` has a different number of elements (with possibly no correspondence to which color goes with which which object in `oldDict`)? Bottom line, what really is `oldDict` and what are you going to be doing with `newArray`. A little more context might help us to provide better answers.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `compactMap` instead of `map`, because `compactMap` does not return elements which are nil and in closures just unwrap color with guard let statement

```
let newArray = oldDict.compactMap {
    guard let color = $0.color else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIColor(hexString: color)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways to do that:

```
let newArray1 = oldDict
    .filter({ $0.color != nil })
    .map({ UIColor(hexString: $0.color! )})

let newArray2 = oldDict
    .flatMap({ $0.color })
    .map({ UIColor(hexString: $0) })
```

Comment: You can use a single `flatMap` as well, which lowers the time complexity of your algorithm. `let newArray = oldDict.flatMap{ if let color = $0.color {return UIColor(hexString: color)} else {return nil}}`. A consecutive `filter` and a `map` operation can always be combined into a single `flatMap`. Using a `flatMap` and afterwards a `map` is a bad idea unless you are actually flattening the array (which you don't do in your code).

Comment: Well, you are right, it's O(n) vs O(n), but the constant is still lower, so the time complexity is reduced.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ah sorry, I guess you are strictly correct; the asymptotic time complexity remains constant though :) Although that being said, unless this bit of code is proven to be performance bottleneck in OP's program, I wouldn't attempt to prematurely optimise it. `.flatMap{ $0.color }.map{ UIColor(hexString: $0) }` is clean and readable, more so than a single `flatMap` in this case IMO.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, I did some tests and it turns out that `.flatMap().map()` pattern is not that bad.  Total loss is at `.filter().map()`, actually.  That being said, I prefer clarity of intent over premature optimisation.